# How to display specific value from database to a page using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I'm new to php and mysql and I got stuck here. I have a database that stores image paths. And these images are then displayed on page. Now, I have a column called "upvotes" in the database table and all I want to do is display this value "upvotes" from database to the php page - under each image it's own value. I'd also like to be able to increase or decrease the "upvotes" value directly from the page and order the images from most upvotes to least upvotes.

Here's the code to display images:

```
<?php
    $query_image = "SELECT * FROM acc_images";
    $result = mysql_query($query_image);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<img alt="" src="images/'.$row["image"].'"><br><br>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'File name not found in database';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You will need JS/Ajax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To specify data returning from your database you need to refine your MySql query.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT 'ColumnName' FROM `table` WHERE 'value' = '1'");
```

The `*` in your MySql query mean select all data.

You want something like this

`$query_image = "SELECT 'upVotes' FROM acc_images";` 
Asuming your upVotes column is in your acc_images table.

**Please note that the Mysql functions are deprecated** and you should be using the MySqli functions, https://www.php.net/mysqli

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query